# Python Print List in a Sentence (Dynamic List)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stuck in a section of my code that I need to manipulate.  This list isn't always going to have a length of 4.  Sometimes it could be 1, 10, or 20; just depends.

```
mylist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
length = len(mylist)
print(f'Here are the addresses: "mylist[1]" "mylist[2]" "mylist[3]" "mylist[4]"')
```

Need the output to look like this:

```
Here are the addresses: "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4"
```

I'm not sure how to put that in a for loop

Comment: Should you say `print(f'Here are the addresses: {mylist[0]} {mylist[1]} {mylist[2]} {mylist[3]}')` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just join it with `str.join` and then print. For eg.

```
mylist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
print_list = " ".join([f'"{addr}"' for addr in mylist])
print(f"Here are the addresses: {print_list}")
```

This will not consider how many elements are going to be there, it merges everything and prints.

Comment: `" ".join([f'"{addr}"' for addr in mylist])` --> `" ".join(f'"{addr}"' for addr in mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this

```
mylist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
length = len(mylist)
print('Here are the addresses: "{0}" "{1}" "{2}" "{3}"'.format(*mylist))
```